# Excel graph function different from cell function

Tags: excel, formula

In an excel graph the function is listed as y= 2E+08x^-3.987 on the graph

On the graph it says the result of setting x = 100 is 1.8

However, in a cell where I use =2E+08*100^-3.987 I get the result of 2.12

Am I missing something?

Thanks.[image: Grpah]

Edit: 
Graph  =Sheet1!$C$14:$C$15,Sheet1!$I$14:$I$15

C14: 100

C15: 120

I14: 1.77

I15: 0.86

Comment: What are the exact number you used to create the graph? So we can reproduce.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've updated the post with values.

Comment: I get very different value for the equation.  What kind of trendline are you adding?  Also, if you want to compute based on the graph trendline formula, you need to format the values to show all 15 decimal places.  And I assume the `177` is either an error or a typo.  Please correct.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry, yeah 177 should've been 1.77 I've updated the post.

Comment: And what kind of trend line?

Comment: @ScottCraner Using his values, and a Power trendline, I get, showing on the graph and formatted to display all the significant digits:  `y = 146513907.298788x ^ -3.95895279205302` and using that formula results in the correct answer of 1.77

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Power formula

Comment: @RonRosenfeld learned something new today, thanks.  Wish I knew that 4 years ago, but alas, no.  I had this same discussion with my boss, that where I found the formulas to prove my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph default setting rounds the numbers to save space on the graph.

You can right click the formula and select the properties then change the decimal places to show greater precision.

To make it easier to use the numbers, since you cannot reference the formula on the graph you can use these formulas to return the proper numbers outside the graph and this returns the whole number without rounding.

Assuming `y = a*x^b`

to get `a`:

```
=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(I14:I15),LN(C14:C15),,),1,2))
```

To get `b`:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(LN(I14:I15),LN(C14:C15),,),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, I'm not particularly confident I understand the ins and outs of your post but it definitely offers the solution I'm looking for 

Weird thing is when I used `=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(I14:I15),LN(C14:C15),,),1,2))` I ended up with  166673634.6
 where you appear to have received 146513907.298788.

Nonetheless you've solved my problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SOliver my bet is that the numbers are supplied via a formula and the precision show is only to two significant digits.  So your numbers may be more like `1.7699876` and `.861234565467` when showing more digits.